# Why cant Newtonsoft.Json deserialize a Dictionary list

Tags: json.net

nvlst declared here then populated

```
Dictionary<string, string> nvlst = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

When the service is finished, it returns

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nvlst, Formatting.Indented)
```

When the client attempts to deserialize, it throws an error

```
alst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(sb.ToString());
```

here is the error message:

```
Error converting value "{
  "Status": "SUCCESS:",
  "CustomerId": "1",
  "LicenseKey": "03bad945-37c0-4fa0-8126-fb4935df396d",
  "MachineFingerPrint": "9B82-A8ED-3DE9-0D8C-26DD-2D83-C17F-C2E3",
  "ExpirationDate": "11/18/2014",
  "LicenseDate": "11/18/2013",
  "LicenseGraceDay": "7",
  "RequireRenewal": "Y",
  "BaseUrl": "http://www.xxx-xxxxxxx.com",
  "HelpUrl": "http://www.xxx-xxxxxxx.com/help",
  "APIUrl": "http://localhost:63583/api/Ajax/runGenericMethodFromApp",
  "CoName": "TestCustomer1",
  "Addr1": "123 Any Street",
  "Addr2": "",
  "City": "Louisville",
  "State": "KY",
  "Zip": "40245"
}" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'. Path '', line 1, position 704.
```

the actual value of the sb.ToString() is below

```
"\"{\\r\\n  \\\"Status\\\": \\\"SUCCESS:\\\",\\r\\n  \\\"CustomerId\\\": \\\"1\\\",\\r\\n  \\\"LicenseKey\\\": \\\"03bad945-37c0-4fa0-8126-fb4935df396d\\\",\\r\\n  \\\"MachineFingerPrint\\\": \\\"9B82-A8ED-3DE9-0D8C-26DD-2D83-C17F-C2E3\\\",\\r\\n  \\\"ExpirationDate\\\": \\\"11/18/2014\\\",\\r\\n  \\\"LicenseDate\\\": \\\"11/18/2013\\\",\\r\\n  \\\"LicenseGraceDay\\\": \\\"7\\\",\\r\\n  \\\"RequireRenewal\\\": \\\"Y\\\",\\r\\n  \\\"BaseUrl\\\": \\\"http://www.xxx-xxxxxxx.com\\\",\\r\\n  \\\"HelpUrl\\\": \\\"http://www.xxx-xxxxxxx.com/help\\\",\\r\\n  \\\"APIUrl\\\": \\\"http://localhost:63583/api/Ajax/runGenericMethodFromApp\\\",\\r\\n  \\\"CoName\\\": \\\"TestCustomer1\\\",\\r\\n  \\\"Addr1\\\": \\\"123 Any Street\\\",\\r\\n  \\\"Addr2\\\": \\\"\\\",\\r\\n  \\\"City\\\": \\\"Louisville\\\",\\r\\n  \\\"State\\\": \\\"KY\\\",\\r\\n  \\\"Zip\\\": \\\"40245\\\"\\r\\n}\""
```

Comment: It looks like the string is getting double-serialized, so that is why it does not deserialize properly.  Are you using a framework like WebAPI or MVC?  Many frameworks automatically handle serialization so there is no need to Serialize/Deserialize results separately.

Comment: Yes, I am using WebAPI, let me try your suggestion

Comment: I can't return it unless I do serialize it.  It throws an error.

Comment: I checked this line on the server,  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nvlst) this is the line that is double serializing the Dictionary

Comment: If you're using WebAPI, then just change your controller method to return the dictionary directly and remove the call to SerializeObject.  I have added an answer below which demonstrates.  I did test this locally and it worked for me without giving an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your string is getting double-serialized, so that is why it is not deserializing properly.  If you are using a framework like WebAPI, it handles serialization for you, so you don't need to call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`.  Instead, change your ApiController method to return the object directly (note that you'll need to change the method signature as well).  For example:

```
public class FooController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public Dictionary<string, string> runGenericMethodFromApp()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dict.Add("Status", "SUCCESS,");
        dict.Add("CustomerId", "1");
        dict.Add("LicenseKey", "03bad945-37c0-4fa0-8126-fb4935df396d");
        dict.Add("MachineFingerPrint", "9B82-A8ED-3DE9-0D8C-26DD-2D83-C17F-C2E3");
        dict.Add("ExpirationDate", "11/18/2014");
        dict.Add("LicenseDate", "11/18/2013");
        dict.Add("LicenseGraceDay", "7");
        dict.Add("RequireRenewal", "Y");
        dict.Add("BaseUrl", "http://www.xxx-xxxxxxx.com");
        dict.Add("HelpUrl", "http://www.xxx-xxxxxxx.com/help");
        dict.Add("APIUrl", "http://localhost:63583/api/Ajax/runGenericMethodFromApp");
        dict.Add("CoName", "TestCustomer1");
        dict.Add("Addr1", "123 Any Street");
        dict.Add("Addr2", "");
        dict.Add("City", "Louisville");
        dict.Add("State", "KY");
        dict.Add("Zip", "40245");
        return dict;
    }
}
```