# Error while pasing JSON

Tags: c#, json.net

While I am trying to call the

```
  `var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserModel>({myjsonString})`
```

it keeps throwing me unable to deserialize exception.
To check if my json string was well formed i decided to 
Parse the string and called

```
JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse({myjsonString});
```

now i get the error below, not quite sure what it means

> Additional information: Expected object while parsing schema object,
>   got String. Path ''

```
**UPDATE**

"{\"Id\":5,\"Username\":\"Sid\",\"FirstName\":\"Sid \",\"LastName\":\"LastSid\",\"Email\":\"test@gmail.com\",\"Password\":\"sample\",\"GravatarHash\":\"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f4f901415af5aff35801e8444cd5adc1?d=retro&?s=50\",\"Country\":\"Moon\",\"OrganizationId\":1,\"IsLocked\":false,\"CreatedDate\":\"12/13/2013 2:34:28 AM\",\"UpdatedDate\":\"12/13/2013 2:34:28 AM\",\"DataLoaded\":true}"
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
"\"{\\\"Id\\\":5,\\\"Username\\\":\\\"Sid\\\",\\\"FirstName\\\":\\\"Siddharth \\\",\\\"LastName\\\":\\\"Kosta\\\",\\\"Email\\\":\\\"Skosta@gmail.com\\\",\\\"Password\\\":\\\"PAssword\\\",\\\"GravatarHash\\\":\\\"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f4f901415af5aff35801e8c4bcd5adc1?d=retro&?s=50\\\",\\\"Country\\\":\\\"India\\\",\\\"OrganizationId\\\":1,\\\"IsLocked\\\":false,\\\"CreatedDate\\\":\\\"2013-12-13T02:34:28.037\\\",\\\"UpdatedDate\\\":\\\"2013-12-13T02:34:28.23\\\",\\\"DataLoaded\\\":true}\""
```

The User Model

```
  public class UserModel
    {
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }
        public String Username { get; set; }
        public String FirstName { get; set; }
        public String LastName { get; set; }
        public String Email { get; set; }
        public String Password { get; set; }
        public String GravatarHash { get; set; }
        public String Country { get; set; }
        public Int32 OrganizationId { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsLocked { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

I also tried

```
public String CreatedDate { get; set; }
public String UpdatedDate { get; set; }
```

thinking if the dates were causing a problem

Comment: Can you please provide us with your json string and UserModel?

Comment: @JevgenijNekrasov provided the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your JSON is getting double serialized.  (Having a bunch of extra backslashes in your JSON is a symptom of this.)  I notice in the comments on another answer that you said you are using Web API.  The Web API framework takes care of serialization for you, so you do not need to call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` in those methods.  Instead just return your result directly.  Then you should be able to deserialize it normally in your client.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20055978/10263).

Comment: Yes tha exactly was the problem. I was trying to serialise it twice and because of which Restsharp was not able to take care of it.

Answer (score 2):

Update:

It works perfectly fine with your `UserModel`, at least for me.

Assume you have such `UserModel`:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string GravatarHash { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }

    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }

    public bool IsLocked { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    public bool DataLoaded { get; set; }
}

var input =
    "{\"Id\":5,\"Username\":\"Sid\",\"FirstName\":\"Sid \",\"LastName\":\"LastSid\",\"Email\":\"test@gmail.com\",\"Password\":\"sample\",\"GravatarHash\":\"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f4f901415af5aff35801e8444cd5adc1?d=retro&?s=50\",\"Country\":\"Moon\",\"OrganizationId\":1,\"IsLocked\":false,\"CreatedDate\":\"12/13/2013 2:34:28 AM\",\"UpdatedDate\":\"12/13/2013 2:34:28 AM\",\"DataLoaded\":true}";

var userModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserModel>(input);
```

I think the problem with your model, can you please provided it?

Comment: updated in the question above. Yes I am using datetime I just tried string just to see if that was causing the problem.

Comment: dosent seem to work for me.I am serialising the object on my webapi and passing it across as a Json string to my client where I again deserialize it . Could there be a problem ??

Comment: it's hard to say what's going wrong during serialization/sending/deserialization process, we need more details and probably you can create new thread for that.

Comment: I am looking into it and looks like i might have missed out on something. I will update the thread as i get to a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the effort @javgenij it was a mistake at my end,

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you have the curly braces in

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserModel>({myjsonString})
```

That seems like the source of the error. Change it to:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserModel>(myjsonString)
```

Comment: Those signify place holders

Comment: Oh I see, sorry for missing that. A good test is to copy your string and go to Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes in Visual Studio to see whether it pastes correctly. You can also test with this site: http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the DataLoaded property.

```
public bool DataLoaded { get; set; }
```

In future, use this website to generate your C# classes from JSON.

http://json2csharp.com/

---

EDIT:

Try this step by step...
Copy and paste this class exactly as is.

```
public class UserModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string GravatarHash { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public bool IsLocked { get; set; }
    public string CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public bool DataLoaded { get; set; }
}
```

Now in the console have this:

```
    var jsonString = @"{""Id"":5,""Username"":""Sid"",""FirstName"":""Sid "",""LastName"":""LastSid"",""Email"":""test@gmail.com"",""Password"":""sample"",""GravatarHash"":""http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f4f901415af5aff35801e8444cd5adc1?d=retro&?s=50"",""Country"":""Moon"",""OrganizationId"":1,""IsLocked"":false,""CreatedDate"":""12/13/2013 2:34:28 AM"",""UpdatedDate"":""12/13/2013 2:34:28 AM"",""DataLoaded"":true}";
    var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserModel>(jsonString);
    Console.WriteLine(user.Country);

    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: it doesn't matter, JSON.NET serializer will ignore the value in that case.

Comment: Updated, taking you step by step all the way to the end